# How to assign an if statement to a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I have an if statement which is used many times in my script:

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo [$JOB_NAME] failed.
        exit 1
    fi
```

is it possible to define a variable and assign this statement to it, and then call it each time I need ti?

Example of use:

```
echo [$JOB_NAME] extracting manifests...
    unzip -o ZIP_FILE "*.yml"
    # Push the app to CF
    cf push -f $MANIFEST_FILE -p ZIP_FILE $NEW_APP 
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo [$JOB_NAME] failed.
        exit 1
    fi
```

Comment: Usually, one assign values to variables and code snippets to functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this should be a function, which could be written like this:

```
ensure_success () {
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "no command passed to ensure_success."
    elif ! "$@"; then
        echo "[$JOB_NAME] failed."
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

`"$@"` expands to the full list of arguments passed to the function. I added a check based on Inian's suggestion in the comments, to ensure that at least one argument is passed to the function.

This combines running the command and checking the error code, so you can use it like:

```
ensure_success command arg1 arg2 arg3
```

So, based on the example in your question it would be:

```
ensure_success cf push -f "$MANIFEST_FILE" -p ZIP_FILE "$NEW_APP"
```

The quotes are free.

I'm not sure where `$JOB_NAME` is defined but presumably it is a global.

Comment: This beats my answer(`++`) i was composing, but with just a small improvement suggest, may be check zero arguments alone in the function like `(( "$#" > 0 )) || { printf "fewer arguments received\n"; exit 1; }`

Comment: @tom not important $JOB_NAME, I don't understand why ensure_success command arg1 arg2 arg3 because my use is like the example I provided in the question (see update)